# Desktop effects could not be enabled with Intel 82G35

Tags: compiz, graphics, intel-graphics

I moved an Ubuntu installation (i.e the hard drive) to a new machine, and while everything went alright, I had to delete xorg.conf to get X running. Now, Gnome is running fine, but I can't get desktop effects to work.

Here's my lspci specs:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device d701
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
Memory at e0200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 3440 [size=8]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915[/CODE]
```

I tried working with the suggestion in this page: [How to Enable Intel Graphics Driver for Ubuntu 10.10](http://www.downloadatoz.com/driver/articles/how-to-enable-intel-graphics-driver-for-ubuntu-10-10.html) but to no avail. Any help/further information I need to supply would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

The 82G35 graphics chipset is a little old now and as you have found, is not well supported in terms of 3D graphics/hardware acceleration etc.

From [here](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/X/UxaTesting), version 10.04 of ubuntu had the ability to force use older graphics drivers.  According to the table, compiz was available when you forced use "uxa" in your xorg.conf file.

In version 10.10, a newer version of the graphics drivers was installed - this didnt have the ability to
 "retrograde" your graphics driver.

My advice would be to 
a. try 10.04 but with the alteration in the xorg.conf file
b. try switching-on software windows effects i.e. [metacity](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9576284&postcount=5)
c. try using a simple compositing manager like [xcompmgr](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xcompmgr) for some simple desktop effects (look for this in software center or synaptic manager)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. While xcompmgr is a good suggestion for the premier reason I want desktop effects (faster screen rendering), I don't know whether it will enable me to work with the new dektop shells (Unity/Gnome Shell) which inherently need Compiz. Any thought wrt that?

Comment: Unity (with compiz) is unlikely to work because of its reliance for newer graphics cards and its opengl requirements.  You could try booting the Natty beta from a USB stick to see if it works.  More likely is Unity 2D - you can install this from the Natty repository.  Gnome Shell doesnt require compiz but has its own compositing manager (mutter).  Again this needs newer graphics - but I dont know if it will work with your graphics card.  Fedora are calling for beta testers.  There is also a gnome 3 ppa you can try.  Make sure you have a good backup though if things dont work out.

Comment: I already tried installing either Gnome 3 and Unity. I haven't looked into Unity 2d that much though